# How to convert unusual datetime formats in excel to year, month, day, and time cells respectively?

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I need to sort a large number (100k+) rows of Excel cells by date and time, however, the date and time for each row are currently provided in a single cell in the following format:

09/03/2018@01:15:00.000 PM

For whatever reason, I'm unable to convert this value into separate cells for year, month, date, and time respectively. Any attempts thus far have produced #VALUE ! errors.

I'm mostly familiar with basic methods of manipulating date and time values in Excel, and I've already attempted using DATETIME as well as converting to date, text, datetime serial.

As mentioned, I've attempted every possible solution that comes up as a result of a google search for "datetime conversion in Excel" and I'm aware of the plethora of existing questions on stackoverflow along this same vein, but none of them really addressed this specific format that I just can't seem to overcome.

Comment: I sometimes revert to left(), right() and mid() and just cut-out the values I need from the string.  So assuming the value is a1, something like =date(mid(a1,7,4), mid(a1,3,2), left(a1,2))

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Excel sees `09/03/2018@01:15:00.000 PM` as a text string.

To make it a date we need to remove the `@` with SUBSTITUTE:

```
--SUBSTITUTE(A1,"@"," ")
```

then you can use the standard YEAR(),MONTH(),DAY()

```
=YEAR(--SUBSTITUTE(A1,"@"," "))
```

...

and so on.

Time would be:

```
=MOD(--SUBSTITUTE(A1,"@"," "),1)
```

And format the output `HH:MM:SS`

[image]